# Installing ASP.NET and MVC 5 on Ubuntu server in VirtualBox

Tags: 14.04, server, mono

I've followed the instructions [here](http://otac0n.com/blog/2015/02/08/running-mvc5-applications-on-ubuntu-server.html) and at the locations that blog post links to in order to install mono, libuv, and kvm on a virtual instance of Ubuntu 14.04. Everything seems to have worked fine until I get to the point where you download an example project from git and test things out using `k kestrel`.

When running that command, I get the following error text:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to load application or execute command 'Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting'. Available commands: web, kestrel.
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ThrowEntryPointNotfoundException (Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.Exception innerException) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.ExecuteMain (Microsoft.FrameworkRuntime.DefaultHost host, System.String applicationName, System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at Microsoft.Framework.ApplicationHost.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I've attempted several fixes, including installing different versions of kvm, to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

System info: Clean install of Ubuntu 14.04 server on a VirtualBox machine, upgraded. The first commands run on the machine were from the already-mentioned sources.

Comment: Similar error message:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518643/asp-net-vnext-on-linux-ubuntu-14-04